# Моя переменная вместо ['usd']

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пж, у меня тут

```
f'Ethereum — {price["ethereum"]['usd']} $\n'


Тут ['usd'] а мне надо чтобы была моя переменная valuta_option в которой у меня текст pln
```

Comment: В чем проблема поменять `['usd']` на `valuta_option`?

Comment: `f'Ethereum — {price["ethereum"][valuta_option]} $\n'`

Comment: @Namerek спасибо помогло закрыто.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
f'{price["ethereum"][valuta_option]} $\n'
```

И всё